# How to read a non-standard space delimited data into a DataFrame and build a GLM model using it?

Tags: csv, julia

I am trying to read a tab delimited file with all data present into julia. It saves all the columns as `NullableArrays.NullableArray{Int64,1}` although I specified the type:

```
data = CSV.read("../datasets/baby.dat"; delim='\t', types=[Int, Float64, Float64, Float64, Float64, Float64])
```

The dataset is from http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/baby.dat

I want to do a regression with the dataset, but the glm.jl Package gives an error with Nullable Arrays ...

Any ideas?

The complete error message is:

```
fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, @formula(Survival2 ~ 
Weight+Age+X1.Apgar+X5.Apgar+pH), data, Binomial(), ProbitLink())

ERROR: Non-call expression encountered

Stacktrace:
[1] dospecials(::Expr) at 
/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/statsmodels/formula.jl:97
[2] collect_to!(::Array{Symbol,1}, 
::Base.Generator{Array{Any,1},DataFrames.#dospecials}, ::Int64,::Int64) at 
./array.jl:508
[3] collect_to_with_first!(::Array{Symbol,1}, ::Symbol, 
::Base.Generator{Array{Any,1},DataFrames.#dospecials}, ::Int64) at 
./array.jl:495
[4] _collect(::Array{Any,1}, 
::Base.Generator{Array{Any,1},DataFrames.#dospecials}, ::Base.EltypeUnknown, 
::Base.HasShape) at ./array.jl:489
[5] map(::Function, ::Array{Any,1}) at ./abstractarray.jl:1868
[6] dospecials(::Expr) at 
.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/statsmodels/formula.jl:101
[7] DataFrames.Terms(::DataFrames.Formula) at  
.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/statsmodels/formula.jl:209
[8] #ModelFrame#127(::Array{Any,1}, ::Type{T} where T, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at .julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/statsmodels/formula.jl:333
[9] (::Core.#kw#Type)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Type{DataFrames.ModelFrame}, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ./<missing>:0
[10] #fit#153(::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Type{GLM.GeneralizedLinearModel}, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Distributions.Binomial{Float64}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/statsmodels/statsmodel.jl:52
[11] fit(::Type{GLM.GeneralizedLinearModel}, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Distributions.Binomial{Float64}, ::GLM.ProbitLink) at .julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/statsmodels/statsmodel.jl:52
[12] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
[13] eval(::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
[14] macro expansion at .julia/v0.6/Atom/src/repl.jl:186 [inlined]
[15] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

Comment: Please post the specific error that you get, this way is easier to help.

Comment: Note that you will only get `NullableArray` columns with an outdated version of CSV.jl. See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dataframes-0-11-released/7296/

Comment: Yes, I know ... But I cannot move to DataFrames - I get errors with the Package DataStreams. Do you know how to resolve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to get a `DataFrame`. Unfortunately your file is not tab-delimited. This is how you can load it into a `DataFrame`:

```
using DataFrames
data = split.(readlines("baby.dat"))
types = [Int, Float64, Float64, Float64, Float64, Float64]
df = DataFrame([parse.(t, getindex.(data[2:end], i)) for (i, t) in enumerate(types)],
               Symbol.(replace.(data[1], ".", "")))
```

Observe that I remove `.` from names of columns as later GLM package has problem with them.

Now you can check that all is as desired:

```
julia> showcols(df)
247×6 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name     │ Eltype  │ Missing │ Values           │
├───────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1     │ Survival │ Int64   │ 0       │ 1  …  0          │
│ 2     │ Weight   │ Float64 │ 0       │ 1350.0  …  790.0 │
│ 3     │ Age      │ Float64 │ 0       │ 32.0  …  27.0    │
│ 4     │ X1Apgar  │ Float64 │ 0       │ 4.0  …  4.0      │
│ 5     │ X5Apgar  │ Float64 │ 0       │ 7.0  …  8.0      │
│ 6     │ pH       │ Float64 │ 0       │ 7.25  …  7.35    │
julia> head(df)
6×6 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Survival │ Weight │ Age  │ X1Apgar │ X5Apgar │ pH   │
├─────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1        │ 1350.0 │ 32.0 │ 4.0     │ 7.0     │ 7.25 │
│ 2   │ 0        │ 725.0  │ 27.0 │ 5.0     │ 6.0     │ 7.36 │
│ 3   │ 0        │ 1090.0 │ 27.0 │ 5.0     │ 7.0     │ 7.42 │
│ 4   │ 0        │ 1300.0 │ 24.0 │ 9.0     │ 9.0     │ 7.37 │
│ 5   │ 0        │ 1200.0 │ 31.0 │ 5.0     │ 5.0     │ 7.35 │
│ 6   │ 0        │ 590.0  │ 22.0 │ 9.0     │ 9.0     │ 7.37 │

julia> tail(df)
6×6 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Survival │ Weight │ Age  │ X1Apgar │ X5Apgar │ pH   │
├─────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1        │ 1120.0 │ 28.0 │ 7.0     │ 7.0     │ 7.33 │
│ 2   │ 1        │ 1020.0 │ 28.0 │ 5.0     │ 7.0     │ 7.34 │
│ 3   │ 1        │ 1320.0 │ 28.0 │ 6.0     │ 6.0     │ 7.24 │
│ 4   │ 0        │ 900.0  │ 27.0 │ 5.0     │ 6.0     │ 7.37 │
│ 5   │ 1        │ 1150.0 │ 27.0 │ 4.0     │ 7.0     │ 7.37 │
│ 6   │ 0        │ 790.0  │ 27.0 │ 4.0     │ 8.0     │ 7.35 │
```

Now the GLM part (notice the correct way to call GLM):

```
julia> using GLM

julia> glm(@formula(Survival ~ Weight+Age+X1Apgar+X5Apgar+pH), df, Binomial(), ProbitLink())
StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel{GLM.GeneralizedLinearModel{GLM.GlmResp{Array{Float64,1},Distributions.Binomial{Float64},GLM.ProbitLink},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

Formula: Survival ~ 1 + Weight + Age + X1Apgar + X5Apgar + pH

Coefficients:
               Estimate   Std.Error    z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -0.563327     8.36692 -0.0673279   0.9463
Weight       0.00213458 0.000479601    4.45074    <1e-5
Age           0.0996481   0.0444713    2.24073   0.0250
X1Apgar       0.0698717   0.0646315    1.08108   0.2797
X5Apgar       0.0371294   0.0703724   0.527614   0.5978
pH            -0.624956     1.11015  -0.562946   0.5735
```

You can check that the results are the same as in R for this model.